# PHP-Push: Owncloud integration

Tags: php, blackberry, activesync, owncloud

i have to connect the activeSynch protocol to Owncloud (for blackberry phones).
I have installed php-push 2 (https://github.com/dupondje/PHP-Push-2) but i can't find any example to configure the php-push 2's config.php.

This is my actual config.php

```
define('CARDDAV_PRINCIPAL','contacts'); 
define('CARDDAV_SERVER', 'http://{MY SERVER ADDRESS}');
define('CARDDAV_PORT', '80');
define('CARDDAV_PATH', '/apps/contacts/carddav.php/addressbooks/%u/');
```

Can anyone help me with a working configuration example?

Thx to everyone

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this: https://github.com/arved/PHP-Push-2-owncloud
PHP-push-2 need a different code for carddav on sabredav / owncloud due to not supported command in sabredav